# How to pass as a parameter the name of a function and its parameters?

Tags: c#, lambda

I am trying to write something like that using a generic class

```
MyGenericClass<IMyType> myGenericClass = new MyGenericClass<IMyType>();
myGenericClass.SetMethod( s=> s.MethodOfMyType(), parameter1, parameter2)
```

Having

```
interface IMyType
{
     int MethodOfMyType(string parameter1, string parameter2);
}
```

I am not very familiar with Lambda expression. Is that in anyway possible in C# ?

EDIT :

I am adding the pseudo code for MyGenericClass in order to try to make this clearer :

```
class MyGenericClass<T>
   {
        public SetMethod(....Here I don't know what kind of parameters i should use)
        {
        }
   }
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to figure if its possible to declare a method with parameters that can be used like the first part of  code above. A method from a Generic class that can take as parameters a function from the generic type and the parameters of that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you keep in mind something like this?

```
myGenericClass.SetMethod( (s,p1,p2) => s.MethodOfMyType(parameter1, parameter2), p1, p2);
```

My final code:

```
class MyGenericClass
{
    public void SetMethod<T>(Func<T, string, string, int> method)
        where T : IMyType
    {
    }
}

MyGenericClass myGenericClass = new MyGenericClass();
myGenericClass.SetMethod<IMyType>((t, s1, s2) => t.MethodOfMyType(s1, s2));
```

If you want to pass parameters later you can add them to SetMethod. Or If you want to have "AllInOne" argument you can use [partial function application](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/01/30/currying-vs-partial-function-application/).

```
var str1 = "MyString1";
var str2 = "MyString2";
Func<string, string, IMyType, int> sourceMethod = (s1, s2, t) => t.MethodOfMyType(s1, s2);
Func<IMyType, int> partialMethod = (t) => t.MethodOfMyType(str1, str2);
```